# How can I get the value of a SettingKey like baseDirectory in a function?

Tags: sbt

I've got the following settingKey:

```
val filterValues = SettingKey[Map[String, String]]("filter-values")
```

And so when defining the setting:

```
filterValues := Map(
    "someKey" -> sys.props.get("some.path").getOrElse(localPath("example"))
    …
)

...
private def localFile(path: String): String = ((baseDirectory) { _ / path })(_.getAbsolutePath)
```

But what I'm getting is the following type mismatch:

```
Build.scala:8: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : sbt.Def.Initialize[String]
[error]  required: String
[error]   private def localFile(path: String): String = ((baseDirectory) { _ / path })(_.getAbsolutePath)
```

What's the right way to do this? (for sbt 0.13, btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extract the value of the settings within the setting intializer, and pass it to the function:

```
filterValues := Map(
    "someKey" -> sys.props.get("some.path").getOrElse(localPath(baseDirectory.value, "example"))
    …
)

...
private def localFile(base: File, path: String): String = (base / path).getAbsolutePath
```

Comment: Great. Just slight cleanup:

    … = (base / path).getAbsolutePath